# HTML5 video controls in Chrome: three-dots button doesn't work

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

In Chrome 83 I've added an HTML5 video player to the page, like

```
<video preload="auto" type="video/mp4" src="(...).mp4" controls></video>
```

And for some reason the three-dots button (which expands a drop-down with the Download and Picture-in-Picture buttons) doesn't work - nothing happens on a click.

[image: HTML5 video player example preview]

However, if I clicked "Full Screen" button and the video expanded to the full-screen, the three-dots button becomes functional and works perfectly.

BTW, there are no overflowing transparent elements, this button is clickable (I can see it fades and reacts on mouse events), but provides no effect. The issue is reproducible with JavaScript turned-off.

Why could it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just discovered this is happening when the video placed somewhere inside the block with `transform: translate(0,0);` style applied (even if it's nested).

Removing `transform` property from the ancestor block has fixed the problem.

Comment: How to fix this if not remove transform property from ancestor

Comment: I didn't find any alternative. It might be a Chrome bug, perhaps worth raising a ticket on their bug-tracker.